# How to add digit to MySQL database entry if already exists?

Tags: php, mysql, url, dynamic

I am creating a blogging input system for my website and if there is already an entry URL I want it to create the same URL plus a digit.

So lets use the URL "test" as an example, if the URL test already exists, I would like it to be "test1" if the URL "test1" already exists I would like it to be "test2".

Here's the way I am (not really) doing it now:

So as you can see, it's not really working the way I want. It can only go form "test" to "test1" - how can I make it rename dynamically infinitely?

Edit:

Okay, after the brow beating I recieved I switched everything over to PDO:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$author = $_POST['author'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

$date = new DateTime('now');
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');

$domainurl = 'https://test.com/entry.php?';
$maxlength = (75 - strlen($domainurl));

if (strlen($_POST['title']) > $maxlength) {

    $url = wordwrap($_POST['title'], $maxlength);
    $url = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "\n"));
    $url = strtr(strtolower($url), ' ', '-');

}else{

    $url = strtr(strtolower($_POST['title']), ' ', '-');

}

$url = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $url);

try {
    $options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    ];
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM blog WHERE url = ?"; 

    $sql = $conn->prepare($sql); 
    $sql->execute([$url]); 

    $rowCount = $sql->fetchColumn();

    if ($rowCount >= 1) {

        $url = $url . $rowCount;

    }

    try {

        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO blog (date, title, url, author, content) 
        VALUES (:date, :title, :url, :author, :content)");

        $sql->bindParam(':date', $date);
        $sql->bindParam(':title', $title);
        $sql->bindParam(':url', $url);
        $sql->bindParam(':author', $author);
        $sql->bindParam(':content', $content);

        $sql->execute();

        $rowCount = $sql->rowCount();
        $id = $conn->lastInsertId();

        if ($rowCount > 0) {

            echo json_encode(array ('type' => 'success', 'message' =>"Blog entry created successfully"));

        }else{

            echo json_encode(array ('type' => 'danger', 'message' =>"Blog entry <strong>not</strong> created successfully"));

        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){

        echo json_encode(array ('type' => 'danger', 'message'=>$e->getMessage()));

    }

}catch(PDOException $e){

    echo json_encode(array ('response'=>'error','errorMessage'=>$e->getMessage()));
}
    $conn = null;
```

Once again: the desired behavior I want to happen is if input "test" and "test" already exists then it goes to "test1", if "test1" exists in the database then it is renamed to "test2" and so on.

As far as debugging details go, currently it only goes to "test1" and I don't know how to get it to "test2" and so forth.

Comment: PDO is never NEEDED, however it is always a good idea in PDO or MYSQLI to use prepared and bound parameterised queries. Once you learn how to do it properly, why ever do it badly ever again

Comment: And where does `$url` come from and what will it look like

Comment: Why don't you just count the entries and tack it on to the URL, that's what I'd do instead of adding on each time.

Comment: I hope you weren't thinking that in using `htmlspecialchars()` would help against a possible SQL injection. It doesn't.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Super good idea but if I am submitting "test" it will count for the row "test" and return 1 and that will be "test1" and then there will be a duplicate.

Comment: Ok. Well, see if that answer below solves this. If not, let them know.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - no I wasn't thinking that at all, I'm storing HTML. As I said in my post this is just for me, I'm not worried about injection or else I would have used PDO.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner - the answer below is giving me errors, I actually like your suggestion, if you could give an answer I would love to see how you would do it.

Comment: I'm a little rusty these days. Maybe @Riggs would like to take a shot at it. I'm also not on a machine that has a webserver installed and mysql.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Why was this closed? I never got an answer to my question that worked

Comment: **_Small Point_** ___Not brow beating___ Neither I not @Dharman said you MUST use PDO. We both said you can use either MYSQLI_ or PDO **but the important thing** is to use Parameterised Bound Prepared queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($rowcount >= 1) {
         preg_match_all('/\d+/', $url, $matches);

         $matches = $matches[0];

         if(count($matches)==0)
            $url.=1;
          else
          {
              $digit = $matches[count($matches) -1 ] + 1;
              $url= preg_replace('/'.($digit-1).'/', $digit, $url);
          }
   }
```

For your SQL commands I recommend using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try your suggestion: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Unsupported operand types Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown on line 42

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't solve my problem, it only goes up to "test1" anything after that is just "test1" again...

Comment: Now it works for all cases after adding preg_replace to the else statement